# Create custom page with custom php form on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to create new page on website on WP. Also I created custom php code, which taking date from user and return description from MySQL.

Currently I have this in this way. I created file calendar.php. I put this to my wordpress catalog C:\xampp\htdocs\mayancalendar4\calendar.php. I have access to this by http://localhost/mayancalendar4/calendar.php. Problem is I want put the form and result in middle of page (where the 404 info occur), not on the end.

My calendar.php:

```
<?php
    define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

    /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <section class="container grey-text">
        <h4 class="center">Wybierz dzień</h4>
        <form class="white" action="calendar.php" method="POST">
        <!-- <form class="white" method="POST"> -->
            <label for="day">Day</label>
            <select id="day" name="day">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
            <label for="month">Month</label>
            <select id="month" name="month">
            <option value="1">Styczeń</option>
            <option value="2">Luty</option>
            <option value="3">Marzec</option>
            <option value="4">Kwiecień</option>
            <option value="5">Maj</option>
            <option value="6">Czerwiec</option>
            <option value="7">Lipiec</option>
            <option value="8">Sierpień</option>
            <option value="9">Wrzesień</option>
            <option value="10">Październik</option>
            <option value="11">Listopad</option>
            <option value="12">Grudzień</option>
            </select>
            <label for="year">Year</label>
            <select id="year" name="year">
                <option value="1900">1900</option>
                <option value="1901">1901</option>
                <option value="1902">1902</option>
                <option value="1903">1903</option>
                <option value="1904">1904</option>
                <option value="1905">1905</option>
                <option value="1906">1906</option>
                <option value="1907">1907</option>
                <option value="1908">1908</option>
                <option value="1909">1909</option>
                <option value="1910">1910</option>
                <option value="1911">1911</option>
                <option value="1912">1912</option>
                <option value="1913">1913</option>
                <option value="1914">1914</option>
                <option value="1915">1915</option>
                <option value="1916">1916</option>
                <option value="1917">1917</option>
                <option value="1918">1918</option>
                <option value="1919">1919</option>
                <option value="1920">1920</option>
                <option value="1921">1921</option>
                <option value="1922">1922</option>
                <option value="1923">1923</option>
                <option value="1924">1924</option>
                <option value="1925">1925</option>
                <option value="1926">1926</option>
                <option value="1927">1927</option>
                <option value="1928">1928</option>
                <option value="1929">1929</option>
                <option value="1930">1930</option>
                <option value="1931">1931</option>
                <option value="1932">1932</option>
                <option value="1933">1933</option>
                <option value="1934">1934</option>
                <option value="1935">1935</option>
                <option value="1936">1936</option>
                <option value="1937">1937</option>
                <option value="1938">1938</option>
                <option value="1939">1939</option>
                <option value="1940">1940</option>
                <option value="1941">1941</option>
                <option value="1942">1942</option>
                <option value="1943">1943</option>
                <option value="1944">1944</option>
                <option value="1945">1945</option>
                <option value="1946">1946</option>
                <option value="1947">1947</option>
                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                <option value="1964">1964</option>
                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                <option value="2025">2025</option>
                <option value="2026">2026</option>
                <option value="2027">2027</option>
                <option value="2028">2028</option>
                <option value="2029">2029</option>
                <option value="2030">2030</option>
                <option value="2031">2031</option>
                <option value="2032">2032</option>
                <option value="2033">2033</option>
                <option value="2034">2034</option>
                <option value="2035">2035</option>
                <option value="2036">2036</option>
                <option value="2037">2037</option>
                <option value="2038">2038</option>
                <option value="2039">2039</option>
                <option value="2040">2040</option>
                <option value="2041">2041</option>
                <option value="2042">2042</option>
                <option value="2043">2043</option>
                <option value="2044">2044</option>
                <option value="2045">2045</option>
                <option value="2046">2046</option>
                <option value="2047">2047</option>
                <option value="2048">2048</option>
                <option value="2049">2049</option>
                <option value="2050">2050</option>
                <option value="2051">2051</option>
                <option value="2052">2052</option>
                <option value="2053">2053</option>
                <option value="2054">2054</option>
                <option value="2055">2055</option>
                <option value="2056">2056</option>
                <option value="2057">2057</option>
                <option value="2058">2058</option>
                <option value="2059">2059</option>
                <option value="2060">2060</option>
                <option value="2061">2061</option>
                <option value="2062">2062</option>
                <option value="2063">2063</option>
                <option value="2064">2064</option>
                <option value="2065">2065</option>
                <option value="2066">2066</option>
                <option value="2067">2067</option>
                <option value="2068">2068</option>
                <option value="2069">2069</option>
                <option value="2070">2070</option>
                <option value="2071">2071</option>
                <option value="2072">2072</option>
                <option value="2073">2073</option>
                <option value="2074">2074</option>
                <option value="2075">2075</option>
                <option value="2076">2076</option>
                <option value="2077">2077</option>
                <option value="2078">2078</option>
                <option value="2079">2079</option>
                <option value="2080">2080</option>
                <option value="2081">2081</option>
                <option value="2082">2082</option>
                <option value="2083">2083</option>
                <option value="2084">2084</option>
                <option value="2085">2085</option>
                <option value="2086">2086</option>
                <option value="2087">2087</option>
                <option value="2088">2088</option>
                <option value="2089">2089</option>
                <option value="2090">2090</option>
                <option value="2091">2091</option>
                <option value="2092">2092</option>
                <option value="2093">2093</option>
                <option value="2094">2094</option>
                <option value="2095">2095</option>
                <option value="2096">2096</option>
                <option value="2097">2097</option>
                <option value="2098">2098</option>
                <option value="2099">2099</option>
            </select>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>

    <div>
        <?php

            function count_days_past($days){
                // echo "Licze dla $days";
                // echo "</br>";

                $result = 250 - abs($days);

                if ($result < 0){
                    return count_days_past($result);
                }
                else{
                    return $result;
                }
            };

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                
                $year = $_POST['year'];
                $month = $_POST['month'];
                $day = $_POST['day'];
        
                $start_date = "2021-07-01";
                $selected_date = "$year-$month-$day";
        
                $start_date_time = strtotime("2021-07-01");
                $selected_date_time = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
                $datediff = $selected_date_time - $start_date_time;
                $amount_days = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
        
                // dodaje 1, bo nie uzywam wartosci 0
                if ($amount_days < 0){
                    // echo "Licze dni z przeszlosci";
                    // echo "</br>";
                    $number_of_day = count_days_past($amount_days) + 1;
                    echo "Nr dnia (wstecz)- $number_of_day";
                    echo "</br>";
                }
                else if ($amount_days == 0){
                    $number_of_day = 1;
                    echo "Nr dnia (zero)- $number_of_day";
                    echo "</br>";
                }
                else{
                    $number_of_day = ($amount_days % 250) + 1;
                    echo "Nr dnia (przod)- $number_of_day";
                    echo "</br>";
                }
                
                echo "start date - $start_date </br>";
                echo "selected date - $selected_date </br>";
                echo "amount days - $amount_days </br>";
                echo "nr dnia - $number_of_day </br>";

                //db connection

                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "mayancalendar4";

                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                $sql = "SELECT id, opis, img FROM kalendarz_opisy WHERE id = $number_of_day";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                    echo "<h3>Opis dla dnia nr $number_of_day</h3>";

                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<p>". $row["opis"]. "</p>";
                    }
                    } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                    }
                    $conn->close();
            };
        ?>
    </div>

</html>
```

Its look like and I marked what I want achieve:

[image]

Result of submit:

[image]

Before I tried put my php and html code by wp-admin and edit text on page. Then I have a form on middle of page, but the submit button not working and I don't getting result.

This looks:

[image]

After submit:

[image]

I working with WP first time. I doing this in correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a new page template and assign it to the page so you can easily handle the page.

For the create template create a new file `filename.php` in parent or child theme.

Here is code for the create template on the active theme directory check this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/1ibx1iz

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: New page temp // your template name write here

*/
get_header();

// your code

get_footer();
?>
```

Now create a new page and assign that template. check this screenshot:http://prntscr.com/1ibxgj9 and publish the page after viewing the page so you can see your custom design.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I put code like you show me and now the form is on the middle, but not working. After submit Chrome go to http://localhost/mayancalendar4/kalendarz2/calendar.php. Look at my form above, I have action="calendar.php". I tried remove part with action but still not working. How make that form calls same page itself?

Comment: Where you created that file in the theme? can you please share path and theme name

Comment: Yes, sure. Theme is jupiter. Path is C:\xampp\htdocs\mayancalendar4\wp-content\themes\jupiter\calendar2.php. I change also in action part to 'calendar2.php'

Comment: The path is correct and has you assign the template to the page right? if yes then please start the error reporting in your file so you can check where you can get the error.

Comment: Yes, I use 'Calendar2' on template. You mean by start reporting this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/turn-on-wordpress-error-reporting/ ? Where I can see the logs/errors?

Comment: Yes, put this code in your template in starting and open the console or on-page you can see the error.

Comment: Try to add    get_template_directory_uri()/calendar.php  
This function will return the absolute path of your calendar.php inside your theme directory

Comment: I get error: POST http://localhost/mayancalendar4/kalendarz2/calendar2.php 404 (Not Found). I don't have 'kalendarz2' directory. Why WP searching there?

Comment: check your code wisely. error in your code and page and template working fine. so if this is helpful then please accept the answer so others can get the answer easily.

Comment: Error in my code working fine? I don't understand. I want eliminate this error

Comment: As per your question, my answer is perfect. you getting errors because of your code. so kindly please check the your code @Bob

Comment: Did you try to add the function I mentioned above, in order to see if that works? Inside form action attribute, try this:
    <form class="white" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/calendar.php" method="POST">
    ....
    </form>    
    
WordPress does not recognize the path, if you use a relative one

Comment: try with <form class="white" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/calendar.php" method="POST">

Comment: After put action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/calendar2.php" I get error:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mayancalendar4\wp-content\themes\jupiter\calendar2.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mayancalendar4\wp-content\themes\jupiter\calendar2.php on line 6. I tried delete get_header() and get_footer() functions, but then I have only label on site and no theme.

Comment: check your wisely because in your code something is messup

Answer (score 0):

It is not the good way actually. You should follow the WP standards to do these modifications. Although, check your WordPress files, inside path:

```
wp-content/themes/your_themes/404.php
```

This is the file responsible for 404 not found page. You could create a **child-theme** (if you do not have yet), create a file 404.php inside your child theme and edit/modity it according to your needs.

*Useful links on how to create a child-theme, could be found here*:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/

Another link to create **custom** **404** **page** on your website:
*Method 2. Create a Custom 404 Page in WordPress By Adding Code*
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-improve-your-404-page-template-in-wordpress/

Comment: so if i want this form to work then i should write a workaround in 404.php file? I don't quite understand.